# Как найти строку из файла по слову

Tags: строки, kotlin

Суть задания заключается в примитивном переводчике из файла. Строки выглядят таким образом:

```
abaft - на корме,в сторону кормы,с кормы,сзади,позади
abandon - покидать,оставлять,отказываться от,предаваться (страсти,несдержанность)
```

Как по поиску слова "abaft " вывести его перевод?

Comment: распарсите построчно содержимое файла по первому `-` в словарь, а затем выводите по ключу

Answer (score 0):

Если данных в файле не так много, то можно сразу считать все строки из файла и положить их в `Map`:

```kotlin
val dictionary: Map<String, String> =
    File("dictionary.txt").readLines().associateBy(
        { it.substringBefore(" - ") },
        { it.substringAfter(" - ") }
    )
```

Теперь распечатаем, например, перевод слова «abaft»:

```kotlin
println(dictionary["abaft"])
```